# How to enable months view in date picker material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently making a date-picker using Material UI in REACT. I'm struggling to find a solution where I can click on the month label/text that will make it show months only.

I can make it show the desired view of months only if i add views={["month"]} prop to the  component.

check this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/8gpxl

If you add `views={["month"]}` as prop in the          component. You will see that it has my desired effect/view. However i'm struggling to find a way i can switch to this view on click of months text.

So in the codesandbox where the datepicker is displayed. I would like to click on 'August 2014' which will then make the `views={["month"]}`

I've tried searching the documentation thoroughly and still can't find a solution. I can't use onChange as that's specifically handling the date, i've tried/thought of doing onClick but that will make it apply to whole component rather than the month label.

I can't seem to find a solution to do it however i feel like it's possible because on the second datePicker in the codesandbox where it doesn't have prop `disableToolbar`. If you click on the year 2014, it then toggles the whole datePicker view to the years. I need it do the same for months when i click on August 2014. So it does seem possible, just need a little help figuring out how.

Comment: Do you want to make use of the toolbar in the datepicker or do you want to implement it without toolbar? Because you can replace the toolbar component with a custom one, where you could implement that onClick that you want.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use the toolbar as I want to use as much of the Material UI functionality as possible. Does it seem possible for you?

Comment: Yes it is possible, the library offers you the opportunity to create a custom Toolbar and insert it as a prop in your datepicker. Look it up [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker) on the props section that you can create a small functional component for your own toolbar.